# Разбор по членам предложения. «Кто есть кто, не понятно»

Tags: члены-предложения

Нужно разобрать следующее предложение:
«Кто есть кто, не понятно.»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь два возможных варианта:

(1) ***Кто есть ктО — непонЯтно.***

СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, союзное слово КТО (подлежащее в придаточном предложении). Повышение тона перед увеличенной паузой обозначается тире.

(2) ***Кто есть кто, непонЯтно.***

Простое предложение, осложненное вводным словом "непонятно". Это вариант СПП, где использована структура и интонация простого осложненного предложения. Понижение тона в конце фразы.

Разбор простого предложения (кто кем является): КТО — подлежащее, ЕСТЬ КТО — именное сказуемое.

Comment: «Простое предложение, осложненное вводным словом "непонятно"» — разве есть такое вводное слово — «непонятно»? Вводное слово можно безболезненно выкинуть, — и какой смысл имеет это предложение без слова «непонятно»? «Кто — есть кто»? Ну и что это значит?

Comment: У нас нет списка вводных слов. Кто есть кто – устойчивое сочетание с определенным значением.  https://phraseology.academic.ru/5918/Кто_есть_кто  Обычно оформляется  так же, как придаточное, но иногда встречаются примеры и другого оформления. Хотела прокомментировать ваш ответ (и даже похвалить отчасти), но теперь сомневаюсь…

Comment: Это тема для диссертации...  Но  я  попробую ответить, но только не в комментариях. А на Грамоте дан  список слов, которые "замешаны" в этой теме, не более того.

Comment: «У нас нет списка вводных слов» — это у вас его нет, а на священной Грамоте.ру он есть: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-alphabet Попутно задам вопрос: если бы такого списка действительно не было, означало бы это, что вводным может быть абсолютно любое слово? А если не любое, то каковы критерии пригодности слова на предмет вводности? «Кто есть кто – устойчивое сочетание с определенным значением» — по-вашему, то, что можно разбирать по членам предложения, может являться устойчивым сочетанием с определённым значением (и наоборот)? «Но теперь сомневаюсь…» — в ком?

Comment: «Но я попробую ответить, но только не в комментариях» — а как? «А на Грамоте дан список слов, которые "замешаны" в этой теме, не более того» — в какой «этой»?

Comment: Эти слова замешаны среди вводных слов.  Отвечу вам как обычно: задам на форуме подходящий вопрос (я и так собиралась это сделать), Послушаю, что скажут, а потом дан на него свой ответ.  А устойчивость - понятие  весьма неопределенное... разные конструкции так называют (фразеологизмы всех сортов, афоризмы и т.д.). А вы и для них готовы правила найти.

Comment: «Эти слова замешаны среди вводных слов» — а что значит «замешаны среди»? Это то самое, что пишет по ссылке сама Грамота:  «В списке представлены как слова, у которых «вводное» значение является основным, так и слова, употребление которых в качестве вводных – относительно редкое явление» или «замешаны среди» — это что-то другое? Кстати: Грамота где-нибудь написала, что список НЕ исчерпывающий? «А вы и для них готовы правила найти» — я? :) Это вы готовы.

Comment: Вы подбираете правила для устойчивых выражений. А вводность – это всего лишь функция, но не часть речи. У эти слов есть только "значение". В словарях обычно пишут – употребляется в значении вводных слов. Такой вот парадокс: значение есть, а форму напрокат берут.

Comment: «Вы подбираете правила для устойчивых выражений» — я подбираю??!! «А вводность – это всего лишь функция, но не часть речи» — а я писал, что это часть речи?

Comment: Не писали, так могли бы написать, судя по вашим высказываниям на тему вводных слов. Просто "священная корова", а не слова.

Comment: «Не писали, так могли бы написать» — вам бы быть членом трибунала в 1937 году, Sharon :)))

Comment: Но вопросы вы в основном задаете, так что  как знать...

Comment: «Так что как знать...» — а никак не знать, уважаемая. И, на мой взгляд, не зная, лучше никак и не писать :)

Comment: ...так что как знать, кто есть кто.

Comment: А кто есть кто иногда очевидно :)

Comment: А вы поменьше доверяйте своей очевидности. Мне, к примеру, очевидно, что вас сейчас  отправят в чат.

Comment: А то, что я туда не пойду, вам очевидно? Если нет, то зря :)

Comment: Ну да.  Когда Шарик не хочет идти куда надо, то едет лапами по асфальту.

Comment: То Шарик — видимо, психология Шарика вам понятнее, чем моя :))

Comment: Просто у меня хорошее воображение...

Answer (score 0):

Моя версия: подлежащее — *кто есть кто* (подлежащее, выраженное предложением), сказуемое — *не понятно* (предикатив [категория состояния] с отрицательной частицей **не** и с глаголом «быть» в нулевой форме). Запятую долой, потому что между сказуемым и подлежащим запятые не ставят (но можно поставить тире). Есть возражения?

Кстати, можно разобрать и такой вариант: *Непонятно, кто есть кто*.